# Каким образом можно передать Recaptcha v2 для решения другому человеку

Tags: javascript, php, recaptcha, captcha

Необходимо передать решение Recaptcha v2 другому человеку. Знаю, как это сделать через сервисы решения, по типу rucaptcha или anticaptcha, но необходимо именно собственное решение.

Пробовал банально скопировать необходимый iframe на собственный домен, но в самой recaptcha стоит проверка по домену, поэтому воспроизвести на другому домене его не получится. Может кто-то сталкивался с этой проблемой, подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: у сервисов занимающихся решениями каптч, обычно есть детальные инструкции, что и как им нужно передавать. предполагаю что для "передачи" любому другому человеку подойдет такая же схема. При этом если там есть задания, то они будут другие, результат подставляется методом подставления идентификаторов различных

Comment: Да. Инструкцию читал, необходимый параметр взять смогу. Вот только проблема заключается в том, как восстановить эту же капчу. Потому что на сервисе только описаны необходимые параметры для передачи. А алгоритма восстановления этой капчи у другого человека нет (